# Does the dirac delta function have a residue?

Tags: contour-integration, dirac-delta

I came to this question by looking at the fourier transform of a hyperbolic cosine. Let's say $f(x)=\cosh(ax)$, where $a$ is a complex number and $x$ is real. Then the fourier transform is $F(\omega)=\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(\omega-ia)+\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(\omega+ia)$. So it's the sum of two dirac deltas that take their nonzero values at the complex numbers $z=\pm ia$. I want to know what happens if I integrate along a contour that surrounds one of these numbers (i.e. Does that dirac delta function have  residue?)

I found a few references to this question online but so far have not come to a definitive answer. This is the best [source](http://bado-shanai.net/The%20Table%20of%20Integrals/intResiduesofDiracDelta.htm) I've found so far, but it doesn't seem to answer the question. He seems to integrate along a contour, where the dirac delta actually lies on the contour. So that's not really a residue. I guess this question is related to how to take the inverse fourier transform and recover the hyperbolic cosine, since you would need to integrate along a contour that contains the nonzero values of the dirac delta. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: It is not a residue. It is zero everywhere except for one point, that is the... point.

Comment: The inverse Fourier transform is very easy to do. It is just an integral over an exponential times the sum of two delta functions. So you can substitute the argument +/-$ia$ in the exponent, which gives you $cosh(ax)$. So this has nothing to do with contour integration and residues.

Comment: @M. Wind But the nonzero values of the dirac deltas do not lie on the real line for this example. When you take the inverse fourier transform you're integrating omega from -inf to inf, so you're not passing through the nomzero values of the dirac delta.

Comment: That is true. But it is not a big problem. Because the Dirac delta function is everywhere analytic, you can easily adjust the integration contour so that: (a) the value of the integral remains the same (b) the contour passes through the argument of the delta function. Hence it is straightforward to show that the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ of $f(x)* \delta(x-a-bi)$$dx$ equals $f(a+bi)$.

Comment: For example you can take this path. (1) from $- \infty$ to $a-R$. (2) from $a-R$ to $a-R+bi$. (3) from $a-R+bi$ to $a+R+bi$. (4) from $a+R+bi$ to $a+R$. (5) from $a+R$ to $+ \infty$. The third term picks up the contribution of the Dirac delta function. The other parts do not contribute. Note that the final result is independent of the choice for $R$, which can therefore be arbitrarily small.